# How do I have the keys and values in a php search show up on the same line

Tags: php, json, search

How do I have the keys and values in a php search query on JSON data show up on the same line. My code is listed below and has the key show up and then the value show up on the following line.

```
function funTimes($tree)
{
    echo '<pre>';
    foreach($tree as $key => $item) {
        if (is_array($item)) {
            echo '<pre>', $key ;
            funTimes($item);
            echo '</pre>';
        } else {
            echo '<pre>', $item, '</pre>'; 
        }
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}

print(funTimes($results));
```

one of the outputs is an age field and it has age on one line and then the actual age showing up on the next line.  When I use the following code per below:

```
function funTimes($tree)    
 {
    foreach($tree as $key => $item)   
    {
      if (is_array($item))  
      {
        echo "{<br>";  
        funTimes($item);  
        echo "}<br>";  
      }
      else  
      {
        echo trim($key).": ".trim($item)."<br>";  
      }
    }
}
print(funTimes($results));
```

my output displays as when I use print

key: age
value: 30

and when I use print_r my output displays as:

key: age
value: 30

Using the below code:

```
print "<pre>";
print_r($results);
print "</pre>";
```

gives me the following output:
   [0] => Array
     (
         [key] => age
         [value] => 30
     )

Per Webeng's response below I've updated the answer and this code below gives me the solution I was looking for and has the key and value on the same line:

```
function funTimes($tree)
{
    foreach($tree as $key => $item) 
    {
      if (is_array($item))
      {
        echo "<br>";
        funTimes($item);
        echo "<br>";
      }
      else
      {
        echo $item." ";
      }
    }
}

print(funTimes($results));
```

Comment: what is output of above code and what is needed ?

Comment: what is the problem and what you want?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but this has basically nothing to do with search, or with JSON, or with PHP... it's just an HTML question?

Comment: Hi Lightness Races in Orbit, the function shown above is written in the PHP programming language. The question is regarding a php search query on JSON data. Would you know of a solution to the question above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `<pre>`, it would be much easier to get your result of having the $key and $value of each element of the array next to each other by echoing them in a one lined string:

`echo $key.": ".$item."<br>";`

For example:

```
function funTimes($tree)
{
    foreach($tree as $key => $item) 
    {
      if (is_array($item))
      {
        echo "{<br>";
        funTimes($item);
        echo "}<br>";
      }
      else
      {
        echo $key.": ".$item."<br>";
      }
    }
}
```

Let me know if that worked for you.

---

**Edited:**

From the comment you gave me, it seems that what is causing the different lines might be characters inside your string. Replace this code:

```
 echo $key.": ".$item."<br>";
```

with this code:

```
 echo trim($key).": ".trim($item)."<br>";
```

What the `trim()` function does is it strips away any whitespace characters at the beginning and at the end of the string parameter. Let me know if it works now.

**Edit 2:**

After having read your updated answer and comments, this is the code I came up with:

For example:

```
function funTimes($tree)
{
    foreach($tree as $key => $item) 
    {
      if (is_array($item))
      {
        echo "{<br>";
        funTimes($item);
        echo "}<br>";
      }
      else
      {
        echo $item." : ";
      }
    }
    echo "<br>";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. It didn't work, it's still showing up on different lines with the word key and the word value now being being displayed: key: age
value: 30

Comment: @user2624243 I added a solution that might work to my answer. Let me know if it works now.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried replacing the code above with echo trim($key).": ".trim($item)."<br>"; but the keys and values are still showing up on separate lines. There was no change.

Comment: @user2624243 Ok... can you edit your answer and paste how the result looks like?

Comment: Hi Webeng -- I responded up above with what I'm seeing using the code you supplied.

Comment: @user2624243 I think I know what the problem is. One more thing is needed to be sure, please do a `print_r($array);` to the array you are doing this to and post it in your question. What I believe is happening is that your `$key` value is actually the word `key` in the first iteration and `value` in the second line. If that is the case, there is an easy solution, however the only way to know if that is the case is to view what is inside the array, so a `print_r($array);` would be very helpful.

Comment: Hi Webeng -- I'm seeing the same output when using print_r as well

Comment: @user2624243 ok, edit your answer and show me exactly what the output of print_r is

Comment: Hi Webeng -- I edited my answer above including the output displayed when using both print and print_r.

Comment: @user2624243 ... are you sure that is the output? when print_r is used, you usually get an output similar to: `Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 )`. In your edited answer you had none of those elements, which print_r does output.

Comment: The following code gives the output that you're referring to:print "<pre>";
    print_r($results);
    print "</pre>";

Comment: @user2624243 ok and please update your answer with that specific output so that I can analyse it

Comment: Hi Webeng -- I've added the output above.

Comment: @user2624243 I've added more code to the end of my answer, let me know if now it works properly.

Comment: Hi Webeng thank you very much. Your final solution is the answer I was looking for and has the keys and values displaying on the same line.

Comment: @user2624243 Great! If this answer worked for you, please accept the answer (with a green checkmark) so that future users know this is the answer that worked for you.